# InputBox open after selecting a row

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have simple macro which opens an InputBox when one of the cells in a range is selected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H18:H" &   Worksheets("LookUpLists").Cells(2, "N").Value - 1)) Is Nothing Then
    UserForm1.Show
End If

End Sub
```

Problem I'm facing is that InputBox opens also when I select the whole row.

Do you have any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the amount of cells:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H18:H" & _
    Worksheets("LookUpLists").Cells(2, "N").Value - 1)) Is Nothing And _
        Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then '// <~~ Check number of cells selected is 1

    Userform1.Show

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow all selections (1 or more) that are not an entire row, this should do it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim bEntireRow as Boolean
    With Target
        bEntireRow = .Address = .EntireRow.Address
        '/ Excel evaluates (.Address = .Entirerow.address) as a Boolean True/False and assigns it to bEntireRow
    End With

    If bEntireRow = false and Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H18:H" &   Worksheets("LookUpLists").Cells(2, "N").Value - 1)) Is Nothing Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If

End Sub
```